# Cannot reboot Ubuntu OS reliably

Tags: boot

I am repurposing a Dell Latitude E7240 with a 16Gb mSATA SSD, and have been able to install Ubuntu 18.04. However, when I reboot it, the OS doesn't load, and I have to press  to enter recovery mode. Sometimes I can type fsck -y /dev/sda1 or go into the menu to fix broken packages and grub bootloader but this doesn't always work. I seem to have ~100+ bad blocks, although the SSD is "healthy," so I wonder if there is a way to *exclude them permanently* from being used. I should mention the laptop is missing the main battery, but the cMOS one is intact. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: If your disk is failing, then _replace the disk_. It will only get worse, and an SSD has a limited lifespan, so you may simply need to replace it, sorry

Comment: Replace the SSD.  Increasing badblocks count and unreliable booting attributed to the disks is indicative of drive failure, and the problem will only worsen unless you replace the disk - no other options to fix here

Comment: Dunno what the battery story is, but you can get a 3rd party (non Dell) replacement for about $30

Comment: As I mentioned, Ubuntu was reporting the SSD as "healthy." Is there no way to permanently exclude bad blocks from use?